# TinyCore no space left on device error

Tags: linux, disk-space

I'm trying to un-gzip an archive (which is supposed to be 500MB once extracted according to WinRar) on a TinyCore linux VM. But I get a "no space left on device error". Here are some commands I typed to check :

```
cd /
du -sh
  Output : 641.0M
fdisk -l | grep Disk
  Output :
    Disk /dev/sda : 8589MB, 8589934592 bytes
    Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table
df -ih
  Output : Inodes Available : 243.6K
```

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Make sure the compressed file is not on a read-only file system or in a directory where you don't have write permission.

Comment: @AFH it's in my /home directory (and I also tried as SU), and it's not read-only file system because I got it with a `wget` command

Comment: Does `gzip -l` list the contents, and are the sizes sensible values?

Comment: @AFH there's no -l option on TinyCore's gzip (only -d, -c and -f)

Comment: I can't tell from here what is wrong (maybe it's a problem with `gzip`'s work directory), but you could try copying to the host and viewing and/or extracting there, though if the host is Windows you will lose the owner and permission information. You say the file is an archive: if it's a `.tgz` file you can try using `tar` to extract it.

Comment: The file is a tar.gz but I can still try to untar it directly. I also already decompressed it on my Windows, but it's 500Mo so it's long to transfer...

Comment: It shouldn't take long if you use a shared folder.

Comment: What is the output of `mount`?